# How to use $in in mongoose reference schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 2 schemas 1st is city and second is pincode. Pincode having reference of city. They both look like this

**CITY schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a all city list
var allCitySchema = new Schema({
    cities: {
      type: String
    }
}, {collection: 'allcities'});

var allcities = mongoose.model('allcities', allCitySchema);
module.exports = allcities;
```

**Pincode schemas**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var allPincode = new Schema({
    city_id: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'allcities'
    },
    pincode: {
        type: String
    }
}, {collection: 'pincode'});

var allPincode = mongoose.model('pincode', allPincode);
module.exports = allPincode;
```

Now the problem is when  i tried to fetch all pincode based upon city id for that i tries like this

```
 app.post('/api/getPincodeByCity', function(req, res) {
        console.log("In pincode");
        var cities_id = [];
        cities_id = req.body.cities_id;
        console.log(req.body); // { cities_id: '["5597aa08c0a0beb40be128d4","5597aa2bbb18fefc142b6915"]' }
        console.log(cities_id);
        pincodes.findById( {city_id: { $in: cities_id }}, function(err,pincodeIds){
            if(err) res.send(err.message);
             res.send(pincodeIds);
             res.end('{"success" : "Recieved Successfully", "status" : 200}');
        });
    });
```

But it's not working its giving me this error

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"
```

I also try with `find()` instead of `findById()` method but it giving me this error

```
undefined is not a function
```

Comment: `findById` expects only id string not object. How do get `pincodes` value? Is it the value of requiring pincode schema?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator is not just "strictly" for querying arrays as that can be done with basically any operator for a singular value.

It's actually a "list of arguments" which evaluates to an [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition, [but with shorter syntax](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in):

```
   var idList = ["559e0dbd045ac712fa1f19fa","559e0dbe045ac712fa1f19fb"];

   var pincode = mongoose.model('pincode');

   pincode.find({ "city_id": { "$in": idList } },function(err,docs) {
      // do something here
   });
```

Which as mentioned is short form for this:

```
  pincode.find(
      {
          "$or": [
              { "city_id": "559e0dbd045ac712fa1f19fa" },
              { "city_id": "559e0dbe045ac712fa1f19fb" }
          ]
      },
      function(err,docs) {
          // do something here
      }
 )
```

You are getting an error because you are overwriting the "array" definition with a "string" which is what all "request" objects are unless parsed otherwise.

The other reason for the error is you are calling the wrong method. `.findById()` expects a single argument of the `_id` for the document. To query other fields use `.findOne()` or in this case `.find()` since an `$in` will possibly match more than one document.

Comment: hey i added `console.log(req.body);` output can you help me whats i m doing wrong

Comment: @Sanji I don't see the content of `req.body` in your question. I already told you. 1. You have a singular string and not an array. 2. You are calling methods with the wrong arguments. Follow what is shown in the answer.